# How does hardhat deploy WETH using getContractFactory

Tags: solidity

I found the following code from the [damn vulnerable defi challenges](https://github.com/tinchoabbate/damn-vulnerable-defi/blob/33120e97e9dbe8c297496a99549e6408a3944e95/test/puppet-v2/puppet-v2.challenge.js#L35)

`weth = await (await ethers.getContractFactory('WETH', deployer)).deploy();`

But I dont know where is the WETH source code. It must be available somewhere in local in order for `getContractFactory` to deploy it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getContractFactory()` generally looks for contracts in the project's `contracts` folder and its subfolders.

However this specific project [imports](https://github.com/tinchoabbate/damn-vulnerable-defi/blob/a5d47759c2132175ed8b5b42a6ba28c1e436032d/hardhat.config.js#LL23C10-L23C17) the WETH contract as a dependency from the [solmate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/solmate) NPM package. The NPM package links to a GitHub repo with the WETH source code [here](https://github.com/transmissions11/solmate/blob/main/src/tokens/WETH.sol).